# implements in UML

Tags: actionscript-3, uml

Any idea how I express 'implements' in UML?
I'm trying to write some actionscript classes in starUML with the help of this handy little template tool: 
http://blog.flashmech.net/2008/09/generate-actionscript-3-with-staruml/
I want the tool to generate 'implements Iblah' in the classes but am not sure what connector to use, Aggregation? Dependecy?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starUML tutorial that should help - http://cnx.org/content/m15092/latest/

Comment: Thanks, I just checked it out. Looks like generalization but that's giving me the result of extending the Interface I want to implement it

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance and implementations are represented as Class Level Relationships in U.M.L. class diagram.
Depending on the type of relation you should choose between these two.

I suggest you take a look at this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Class_Level_Relationships